# Transparently read from a form element, whose type is irrelevant, with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, input, radio-button

I'd like to have a function like this

```
// get the value of a form element the way it would be submitted
// by the form
function getVal(fieldName) {
  var $field = $(':input[name=' + fieldName + ']');

  // radio buttons
  if ($field.is(':radio')) {
    return $(':input[name=' + fieldName + ']:checked').val();
  }

  // textarea, input[type=text], select
  else {
    return $field.val();
  }
}
```

The above works well, as it handles both radio buttons and other types of form input (not checkboxes, but I don't care for the moment).

I was wondering if jquery didn't already have such a function or selector built-in that I should use instead? Because to me, radio buttons are exactly the same as selects, functionally (single-select choice). I don't see why I should treat any differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of people would agree that that is the way `val()` *should* work (based on the number of questions about getting radio-button values).

And it's strange because:

1. [`val()` already acts intelligently for `<select>` elements](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-0).
2. [`val()` ***sets*** radio buttons intelligently.](http://api.jquery.com/val/#example-1-2)
   For example, given:

   ```
   <input type="radio"  name="r" value="radio1"/> rad1 txt
   <input type="radio"  name="r" value="radio2"/> rad2 txt
   ```

   Then:

   ```
   $("input[name='r']").val(["radio2"]);
   ```

   checks the correct button!

So why doesn't `val()` ***read*** radio buttons intelligently?  Apparently, because that's how it started out, and there's fear of breaking old code. (Although I don't know if anybody uses `val()` on a single radio-button node to read its unchecked value -- or why anyone would want to.)

Join [the discussion on the jQuery dev forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-val-and-checked).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! So there's currently no way to access values uniformely, not even using some `:checkedIfCheckedIsApplicable` selector...